# Neo4j - Native Java API

Tags: java, neo4j

I tried to implement this code on this link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_native_java_api_example.htm

which is how to connect Neo4j DB with java, but I don't understand **Step4**:

Step 4 - To create Nodes, we need label names. Create an Enum by implementing Neo4j Java API "Label" interface.

```
package com.tp.ne4oj.java.examples;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
public enum Tutorials implements Label {
    JAVA,SCALA,SQL,NEO4J;
}
```

so if they mean put this code in an interface how to do it??

just I need to see my DB through Neo4j app??

Many thanks

Comment: Just create an enum implementing Label where you put every Label you can have in your database.

Answer (score 0):

The point of this step is to define a [Java enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that specifies all the [node Labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j.html#graphdb-neo4j-labels) that you want to use in Neo4j. This enum needs to implement the [Label interface](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Label.html).

So if you want to create Person and Product nodes in your database your labels enum would look like this:

```
package com.my.examples;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;

public enum TutorialLabels implements Label {
    Person,Product;
}
```

Then when you want to reference a node label you use this enum. For example:

```
Node personNode = db.createNode(TutorialLabels.Person);
```